# Anonymize user data completley

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, logging, user-data

I am to build a Rails application (not that it actually matter what framework or language is used) that not only does not collect user data, but actively removes it from the server granting users absolute paranoid anonymity level.

I was thinking about solutions on how to do this and so far I have deduced that, besides not collecting any data and not using any external services:

- using HTTPS
- turning off Rails logging
- disabling session cookies
- turning off or overwriting server access logs

cover most of it. However, I am still not sure if some piece of user data will get written somewhere I did not think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: Outside of FBI jurisdiction. Paranoid client request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things I would look at is your router and firewall.  Sometimes they are configured to log IPs or other user data.

Answer (score 1):

This is helpful. It tells about the simplest way in which you should structure your anonymizer class and related functions.

http://railspikes.com/2009/4/8/how-to-anonymize-data-with-rake